# Python Regex: Using a lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to detect text of the following type, in order to remove it from the text:

```
BOLD:Parshat NoachBOLD:
BOLD:Parshat Lech LechaBOLD:
BOLD:Parshat VayeraBOLD
BOLD:Parshat Sh’miniBOLD:
```

But only to capture this part:

```
BOLD:Parshat Noach
BOLD:Parshat Lech Lecha
BOLD:Parshat Vayera
BOLD:Parshat Sh’mini
```

I thought to use this regex using lookahead:

```
re.sub(r"BOLD:Parshat .*?(?=(:BOLD))","",comment) #tried lookahead with and without parens
```

But it doesn't seem to be detecting them. What might be the problem? The text is followed by a snippet in Hebrew, not sure if that is what is causing the problem.

Please note that these segments are embedded in the middle of different lines, as mentioned followed by a Hebrew snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can just do:

```
str = re.sub(r'BOLD:?$', '', str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qiNd4L/3)

That will remove `BOLD` followed by optional `:` from the end of each line.

---

**EDIT:** If this `BOLD:` term is not always at end of line, one can use:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'\b(BOLD:.*)BOLD:?', r'\1', str)
BOLD:Parshat Noach
BOLD:Parshat Lech Lecha
BOLD:Parshat Vayera
BOLD:Parshat Sh’mini
```

Comment: Should have been clearer, this is not always at the end of a line

Answer (score 0):

You don't need look-around just use a capture group and `re.MULTILINE` flag in order to match a multi line text.

```
In [8]: s = """BOLD:Parshat NoachBOLD:
   ...: BOLD:Parshat Lech LechaBOLD:
   ...: BOLD:Parshat VayeraBOLD
   ...: BOLD:Parshat Sh’miniBOLD:"""

In [9]: re.findall(r'^(BOLD.*)BOLD:?$', s, re.MULTILINE)
Out[9]: 
['BOLD:Parshat Noach',
 'BOLD:Parshat Lech Lecha',
 'BOLD:Parshat Vayera',
 'BOLD:Parshat Sh’mini']
```

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity, but this is not always at the end of a line.